# Запланированное выполнение PHP метода

Tags: php, symfony

Пишу небольшую браузерную игру с бэкендом на php symfony

У каждого игрока отведено время на ход. Требуется на стороне сервера вызвать событие если время закончилось.

Как мне запланировать задачу, которая вызовет метод (или отправит get запрос) через определенное время

---

Сейчас реализовано так:

1. Создается строка в базе данных с временной меткой
2. Запланирован скрипт который каждую секунду проверяет временные метки всех строк
3. Вызывает нужный метод, когда временная метка < текущей

Но я так понимаю это не best practices, ищу менее костыльный вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для таких задач лучше использовать очереди. По сути вы реализовали свой механизм очередей. Но лучше использовать [готовый компонент](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html).

В вашем случае задание в очередь нужно добавить с задержкой(будет выполнено после истечения установленного времени). Для этого также есть готовый [функционал](https://symfony.com/doc/current/messenger.html#envelopes-stamps).

Comment: Нее, очередь тут не пойдет. Задание с задержкой добавите, а через какое время ее возьмет consumer?

Comment: Ровно через то, которое будет указано. Для этого есть например пориоритезация очередей. Так же консюмеров можно "плодить" сколько угодно. Очередь будет тут хорошим решением.

Comment: Допустим у вас один консюмер и 100 задач, на выполнение одной задачи треуется образно одна секунда. Сложилась ситуация, что по всем задачам истек срок и consumer приступил к разбору задач и до последней он дойдет через 100 секунд. Хорошая такая задержка получается.

Comment: Вопрос на самом деле очень интересный, я даже стрелу вверх жмакнул)

Comment: Да, видимо надо выяснить "функциональные требования". Допустима ли задержка и на сколько. В любом случае, на мой взгляд данные проблемы решаются масштабированием решения брокера очередей.

Answer (score 0):

Ввести очередь - типичное решение задачки с ожиданием. Такое решение гораздо лучше всех других (нет костыльных решений проблем, которые появятся - с падением процесса, потерей данных при перезагрузке, зависания ждущих воркеров, проверке их статусов, утечек памяти и прочим).

Вопросы с задержкой исполнения сообщений в очереди - это отдельные вопросы, не связанные с задержкой исполнения, решать их нужно теми способами, которые в этом случае применяются - приоритизация очередей, создание множества воркеров и прочими вещами.